# Singular/Data test missing test_metadata in dbt

Tags: dbt

I am trying to setup a singular test in dbt (it’s a test for one specific table - `TableA`), so I wrote an SQL query which I placed in `tests` folder. It returns failing rows.
However, when I run `dbt test —-select tableA`, in case the test passes (no failing records), I get the following error:

```
14:20:57  Running dbt Constraints
14:20:58  Database error while running on-run-end
14:20:59  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in operation dbt_constraints-on-run-end-0 (./dbt_project.yml)
  'dbt.tableA.graph.compiled.CompiledSingularTestNode object' has no attribute 'test_metadata’
```

In case the test fails, it returns the failing rows, which is correct behaviour.

I am using `dbt_constraints` package (v0.3.0), which seems to be causing this problem, specifically this script which runs in the on-run-end hook https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/dbt_constraints/blob/main/macros/create_constraints.sql

I am guessing I need to add some test metadata to the singular test, but not sure how to do it.

Here is what the test looks like

`tests/table_a_test.sql`

```
SELECT *
FROM {{ ref('TableA') }}
WHERE param_1 NOT IN 
    (SELECT TableB_id
    FROM {{ ref('TableB') }}
    UNION
    SELECT TableC_id
    FROM {{ ref('TableC') }}
    UNION
    SELECT TableD_id
    FROM {{ ref('TableD') }}
    UNION
    SELECT TableE_id
    FROM {{ ref ('TableE') }} )
        and param_2 is null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in that package; I would open an issue in the `dbt-constraints` repo. There is no documented way to add metadata to a Singular test, but that code assumes that all tests will have `test_metadata.name`.

I doubt this would work, but what happens if you add a `schema.yml` file to the `tests` directory, alongside your singular test? The contents would look like:

```yaml
version: 2
tests:
  - name: table_a_test
```

Comment: Great idea! But unfortunately it doesn't work. I'll open the issue in the `dbt-constraints` repo. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your call should be `dbt test —-select table_a_test` instead of `dbt test —-select tableA`. I think, you need to call the test name not the table name, which is already hard coded in the (singular) test. does that work?

Comment: Thanks! But  I get the same error even when running one specific test (i.e. with `dbt test --select table_a_test`. The other command runs all tests for the selected table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the test with a + sign in front of it? Since you are using `ref` in the test, you might need to build everything before test.